# Django-form not rendered in HTML

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

The view that `**renders**` is

```
def codequestion(request, question_id):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/codequestion.html', {'question': question})
```

the view that is called on ***submission*** is

```
def codequestion_evaluate(request, question_id):
    form = CodeForm()
    print request.method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CodeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data        
            return HttpResponse("Your code is  %s" % data['solution'])
        else:
            return HttpResponse("not valid")    
   else:
        return HttpResponse("Error")
```

**class**

```
from django import forms

class CodeForm(forms.Form):
    solution = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**template**

```
<form action="{% url 'codequestion_evaluate' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}   
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I do not get the form field display in the HTML page, I can only see the submit button.

Comment: I'm surprised you'd even see the submit button with that view, what view renders your template?

Comment: i dont get you, the python code i pasted is the view

Comment: You've included the view that gets called when you submit the form (I assume), not the one that renders the template

Comment: <pre><code>def codequestion(request, question_id):
 question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
 return render(request, 'polls/codequestion.html', {'question': question})</code>

Comment: Please use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35538002/edit) button to add new information

Comment: Can you please tell me where i made the mistake? This is my first app so i couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view that is suppose to show the unfilled form doesn't create the form object at all. It should create a form object and pass it to the template, like this:

```
def codequestion(request, question_id):
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    form = CodeForm()
    return render(request, 'polls/codequestion.html', {'question': question, 'form': form})
```

---

But better yet you should follow [the pattern described in Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#the-view). To do this you should:

1. Delete the `codequestion`. All actions (displaying the unfilled form, displaying a submitted form with errors, processing a correctly submitted form) will be handled by a single view.
2. Configure your url routing so `codequestion_evaluate` view handles the page showing the unfilled form.
3. Change `codequestion_evaluate` so it follows the pattern:

   ```
   def codequestion_evaluate(request, question_id):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           form = CodeForm(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               # The form has been submitted and is valid
               # process the data and redirect to a "thank you" page
               data = form.cleaned_data
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
           else:
               # just display an empty form
               form = CodeForm()
       # you can optionally add 'question' if you need it in your template
       question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
       return render(request, 'polls/codequestion.html', {'form': form, 'question': question})
   ```

Comment: Works like charm! Now i get where i missed it

Answer (score 0):

`form` refers to a variable in your context data, since you haven't included it in the context data, it can't find it so there isn't anything to render, you need to include it.

```
def codequestion(request, question_id):

    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
     return render(request, 'polls/codequestion.html',
                   {'question': question, 'form': CodeForm()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
class CodeForm(forms.Form):
```

to

```
class CodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

I faced same problem but it got resolved from this.

Answer (score 0):

The recent distributions of `django` don't have widgets included. So:

```
pip install django-widgets
```

should do the trick.